# <a href></a> button link cannot appear

Tags: php, html

I am trying to import Google contacts using OAuth 2.0 by following this YouTube tutorial: [Tutoriel PHP - Importer des contacts Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysNVe0TaVFs). However, at the moment the button link is not being displayed.

This is the code of my `index.php` file:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"/>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Google Contacts API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Google Contacts API v3.0</h2>
<?php
    require 'config.php';
    require 'lib/google-api-client/Google_Client.php';

    $client_id = '<aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.bbbbbb.cccccccccccc.com>';
    $client_secret = '<e3fsfds4gfg23ha93kmKFkfgK>';
    $redirect_uri = '<http://ccccccccccccccccccc.com/rddddddddddd/index.php>';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client -> setApplicationName('contact');
    $client -> setClientid($client_id);
    $client -> setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client -> setScopes('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');
    $client -> setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client -> setAccessType('online');

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . $google_redirect_uri);
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $url = $client->createAuhUrl();
?>
        <a href="<?=$url; ?>">Import Google Contacts</a>
<?php
    } else {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
        $token->access_token;
        $curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=50&access_token=" . $token->access_token);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $contacts_json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $contacts = json_decode($contacts_json, true);
        $return = array();
        foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
            $return[] = array(
            'name' => $contact['title']['$t'],
            'email' => isset($contact['gd$email'][0]['address']) ? $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'] : false,
            'phone' => isset($contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t']) ? $contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'] :false,
            );
        }
        var_dump($return);
    }       
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**How might I correct this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can only appear if `if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))` is false.

So is the token NOT set?

`echo $_SESSION['token'];` right after `<h2>Google Contacts API v3.0</h2>` to be sure.

Also it is a waste to do this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $url = $client->createAuhUrl();
    ?>
        <a href="<?=$url; ?>">Import Google Contacts</a>
    <?php
} else {
```

Just do this instead:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $url = $client->createAuhUrl();
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Import Google Contacts</a>';
} else {
```

Only punch out of PHP if the HTML content is going to be a significant amount.

Comment: I will try it and tell u in 2 minutes

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness)  - Yes. I am trying to work with your comment  - will reply soon - Thank you

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness)  - it doesn't work - still I can't get the button link - anything else I can do - Thank you

Comment: What was the result of `echo $_SESSION['token'];`

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness) - echo $_SESSION['token']; is printed on screen when I echo it right after <h2>Google Contacts API v3.0</h2>

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness) - i will look it and get back - thank you

Comment: It needs to go after the php opener as well, like this... `<h2>Google Contacts API v3.0</h2>
<?php echo $_SESSION['token'];`

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness) - oh ok  - i thought so

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness) - if i do that, the page is same as before - only showing the content in <h2> tags

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness) - where should i put the error handler code - so that I can find errors

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness) - ok i will do that - thank you

Comment: [Madness](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2940627/madness) - the link can be displayed now but got this now on my site - Notice: Undefined index: token in /var/www/html/restaurant_test/index.php on line 45

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the PHP,

but solution is you have to add some link for href like

```
<a href="www.google.com">test</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#">test</a>
```

Comment: [Swapnil Motewar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4136561/swapnil-motewar) - I will look into it. Will let u know soon

Answer (score 0):

Can you place your code like this you will get to know the issue

```
if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
$url = $client->createAuhUrl();
?>
    <a href="<?=$url; ?>">Import Google Contacts</a>
<?php
} else {
```

Comment: [vamshi goli](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4969184/vamshi-goli) - isn;t it already like that - thank you